# Finiteness in infinite collection of non-cofinite sets implies finiteness?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any set $X$, let $W_X=\{S\subset X\mid X\setminus S\text{ is infinite}\}$.

Does there exist a set $X$ and an infinite set $A\subset X$ such that for all $Y\in W_X$, $A\cap Y$ is finite?

I've been trying to prove the negation of this statement by contradiction for a bit now, but I can't get a grasp on it. Is it true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is false, here goes a improved proof.
As $A$ is infinite there exist a collection of non repeated elements $(a_n)_n\subset A$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then you can pick the subsequence given by $S=(a_{2n})_n$.

Now, $S$ is obiously an element of $W_X$ as $A\setminus S\subset X\setminus S$ and $A\subset S=(a_{2n-1})_n$ which is an infinite set.
Finally $A\cap S=S$ which is an infinite set and that proof tha the statement is false.

Comment: Ah, of course! It is so obvious. Well done, I was being silly.